# Spark/Scala kernel failing on Jupyter due to Java error

Tags: java, scala, ubuntu, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I've been using the Spark/Scala kernel on Jupyter (I'm not sure which version/how to check since it's not listed in `jupyter kernelspec list`).

All of a sudden, it stopped working. Poking around a bit, I've found an error preventing the kernel from initiating:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigMergeable : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

I've seen several threads trying to address this issue ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612054/what-does-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-mean-and-how-do-i-fix-it), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541629/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-in-ubuntu)), but I don't follow them at all / how to apply suggested solutions to my situation.

It appears there's some sort of version mismatch somewhere inside how the kernel's working, but I don't know how to figure out where the mismatch is / how to fix it. I've looked at the following, but don't see (or know how to diagnose, really) any inconsistency:

```
printenv | grep "JAVA"
# JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

java -version
# java version "1.7.0_131"
# OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.9) (7u131-2.6.9-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
# OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.131-b00, mixed mode)

javac -version
# javac 1.7.0_131
```

This is being run on a remote machine, so I only have terminal access to diagnose / fix the problem.